# Haskell - adding quotation marks (speech marks)

Tags: haskell, quotation-marks

Sorry if this is a stupid question but does anyone know of a function which would allow me to enclose a number in quotation marks in Haskell, for example:

function 7777  ->  "7777"

function 1234  ->  "1234"

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you post more of your code so that we can better help you?  This is a really vague question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, convert 7777 to a string?  You can use `show`.

```
show 7777 --> "7777"
```

If you then want quotes around that string do:

```
"\"" ++ show 7777 ++ "\""
```

Comment: erm... At the moment my output from one function is a number, the next function I want to implement (on this number) requires that the number is surrounded by quotation marks, so I want a function that does this so I can combine all three into a single operation, if that makes sense?

Comment: `A number surrounded in quotation marks` Do you mean a string?

Comment: @Michael that should be a String, you can check in GCHi by using `:t yourfunction`

Comment: it's Int -> [e] -> [[e]]